# == check on two fields elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, scripting, compare, equality

I have scenario like where need to check two fields equality.
Assume i have an index **my_index** with mapping

```
    "field_one": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          },
          "regexkeyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": "simple"
      },
     "field_two": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          },
          "regexkeyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": "simple"
      }
```

Here i need to write a query to get the data by matching `field_one` and `field_two`
Here is what i tried

```
 {
 "script_fields": {
     "adas": {
        "script": {
           "inline": "'field_one.keyword' == 'field_two.keyword'",
           "lang": "painless"
         }
     }
 }
```

Note : Elastic version : **5.5.3**

Comment: Your mapping has "filed_one" and "filed_two", but your query refers to "field_one" and "field_two".

Comment: @Adam It's might be a typo, but fields are referred correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the syntax is, but I have no instance in ES .X to test it

```
{
 "script_fields": {
     "adas": {
        "script": {
           "inline": "doc['field_one.keyword'].value == doc['field_two.keyword'].value",
           "lang": "painless"
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: both syntaxes are giving the same result but it not expected data.